# Where is the Core Data sqlite file located for my project?

Tags: sqlite, core-data

I check other questions in the stack overflow, however, the problem is I really download some `sqliteBrowser`, and can not find my project `sqlite`. Somebody told me that the path is "/Users/My_Name/Libray/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices".

I find some many folders in the `Devices`, but which one is my project belongs to?
All the folder's name is like "9EF3A7FD-5F1E-4134-A602-307739CEEE07", I was so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `debugPrint` the path where the sqlite file is created in your `AppDelegate` if you are using the default template from xcode, you will find the line

```
let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Whatever.sqlite")
```

put a

```
debugPrint(url)
```

after that and let the simulator tell you where to look.

The directories' names are UUIDs representing the different simulator instances you have been using over time.

Comment: I add "debugPrint(url)" in my AppDelegate, however, I didn't see the output in the console?

Comment: My bad; I assumed you were actually using core data. The store is initialized lazily. As soon as you use Core Data features in the app, it should pop up. As a quick workaround, add `debugPrint(self.persistentStoreCoordinator)` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really solve me my headache problem!!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, I add this print statement:

print(container.persistentStoreDescriptions)

inside the lazy declaration of persistentContainer, right before returning the container.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "App_Name")

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    })
    print(container.persistentStoreDescriptions)
    return container
}()
```